# svg loader animation loop

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

i need some help creating my SVG loader. I have an animation like this below. When animation starts, each circle become orange. When it is finished, line starts to draw backward (that is ok), but each circle should also become blue. And it also should play in loop. Can you guys help me? Snippet included.

```css
svg {
 width: 100%;
            max-width: 500px;
}

path {
              stroke-dasharray: 2530;
              stroke-dashoffset: 2530;
              animation: draw 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
            }

.circle-big {
  fill: #6085A1;
}

.circle-small {
              fill: #fff;
            }

#circle-1-big {
                animation: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 100ms;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-delay: 0ms;
              }
              
#circle-2-big {
                animation: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 100ms;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-delay: 100ms;
              }              
#circle-3-big {
                animation: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 100ms;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-delay: 350ms;
              }
#circle-4-big {
                animation: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 100ms, 100ms;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-delay: 650ms;
              }
#circle-5-big {
                animation: changeColor;
                animation-duration: 100ms, 100ms;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-delay: 800ms;
              }
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0%   {
    fill: #6085A1;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #EF7B00;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1228 408">
      <g>
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="11" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M51,244L216,71L478,339L762,50L948,238L1139,48"></path>
        <circle class="circle-big" id="circle-1-big" cx="51" cy="244" r="39"></circle><circle class="circle-small" id="circle-1-small" cx="51" cy="244" r="14"></circle>
        <circle class="circle-big" id="circle-2-big" cx="216" cy="71" r="39"></circle><circle class="circle-small" id="circle-2-small" cx="216" cy="71" r="14"></circle>
        <circle class="circle-big" id="circle-3-big" cx="478" cy="339" r="39"></circle><circle class="circle-small" id="circle-3-small" cx="478" cy="339" r="14"></circle>
        <circle class="circle-big" id="circle-4-big" cx="762" cy="50" r="39"></circle><circle class="circle-small" id="circle-4-small" cx="762" cy="50" r="14"></circle>
        <circle class="circle-big" id="circle-5-big" cx="1139" cy="48" r="39"></circle><circle class="circle-small" id="circle-5-small" cx="1139" cy="48" r="14"></circle>
      </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You only need CSS animation or smil SVG too?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT only animation working properly

Comment: I understood correctly that only CSS animation is needed?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT exactly, my animation is included in snippet, but as i said it is not working properly. When its done it should play backwards :)

Answer (score 2):

I've made a few changes to your code:

1. Instead of using 2 circles I'm using only one circle with a thick stroke. Of coarse in this case I'm animating the stroke not the fill.
2. You have a path and you animate the stroke-dashoffset. The problem is that the sections of the path have different length making it impossible to know when to begin the animation of the circles. Instead of only one path I'm using 5 paths and I'm beginning the circle animation at the end of the path animation.
3. In this case you can't use animation-direction: alternate; Instead I'm using 2 concatenated animations. I also need some javascript to know when the second animation is ending so that I can remove the class svg and add it back a little latter.

In order to calculate the delay I'm using css variables but you may need to use a different animation for every segment (for those browsers where variables are not supported). Alternatively you may use javascript. Also I'm using variables to store the length of every path.

As an observation: as @Alexandr_TT is mentioning in it's comments a SMIL animation may be better in this case. And there is a js polyfill for the SMIL animations.

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");

let i = 0;

first.addEventListener(
  "animationend",
  () => {
    i++;
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      svg.setAttribute("class", "");
    }
  },
  false
);

window.setInterval( function(){
 svg.setAttribute("class", "svg");
},15000/60);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

path {
  stroke-dasharray: var(--sd);
  stroke-dashoffset: var(--sd);
  stroke:black;
}
.svg path {
  animation: draw 1s forwards calc(1.5s * var(--n)),
             draw1 1s forwards calc(1.5s * (9 - var(--n)))}

circle {
  stroke: #6085a1;
  stroke-width:30px;
  fill:white;
}
.svg circle {
  animation: a .5s  forwards calc(1.5s * var(--n) - .5s),
             b .5s  forwards calc(1.5s * (10 - var(--n))  - .5s);
 }


@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes draw1 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--sd);
  }
}

@keyframes a {
  0%   {
    stroke: #6085A1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: #EF7B00;
  }
}

@keyframes b {
  0% {
    stroke: #EF7B00;
  }
  100%   {
    stroke: #6085A1;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1228 408" class="svg">
        <!--<path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="11" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M51,244L216,71L478,339L762,50L948,238L1139,48"></path>-->
      
        <g style="--sd:239;--n:0">
        <path id="a" stroke-width="11" d="M51,244L216,71"  />
        <circle cx="51" cy="244" r="30" id="first"></circle>
        </g>
        <g style="--sd:374.79;--n:1">
        <path id="b" stroke-width="11" d="M216,71L478,339" />
        <circle cx="216" cy="71" r="30"></circle>
        </g>
        <g style="--sd:405.19;--n:2">
        <path id="c" stroke-width="11" d="M478,339L762,50" />
        <circle cx="478" cy="339" r="30"></circle>
        </g>
        <g style="--sd:264.46;--n:3">
        <path id="d" stroke-width="11" d="M762,50L948,238" />
        <circle cx="762" cy="50" r="30"></circle>
        </g>
        <g style="--sd:269.4;--n:4">
        <path id="e" stroke-width="11" d="M948,238L1139,48"  />
          <circle cx="948" cy="238" r="30"></circle>
        </g>
       <g style="--n:5">
         <circle cx="1139" cy="48" r="30"></circle>
       </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! Interesting ways to use variables. it is instructive to remember and use them in practice. Thanks enxaneta! The hand of the master is felt everywhere

Comment: @Alexandr_TT That is amazing. I have to make it a little bit faster, and try to fix why when the last circle become orange it's blinking.

Comment: @Marek If you liked **enxaneta's answer**, then it would be good to do upvote on his answer

Comment: @enxaneta Could you please tell me why when line draw to last circle, the last circle only blink? Cant figure this out.

Comment: It's because it returns immediately. On arriving there the circle changes the color from blue to orange and next the other animation begins and the circle goes back to blue